# NSUserDefaults registerDefaults to set initial BOOL - does existence of BOOL value return YES

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I have this `NSUserDefaults` setup code

```
 NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary
                             dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"DidBuyInAppPurchase"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:appDefaults];
```

I check later like so:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"DidBuyInAppPurchase"] == YES){//some code}
```

Does this mean that a BOOL exists for the key or that the key was set to YES?

The odd behavior was that I wrote code in `viewDidLoad` that set the BOOL to YES just to test. Prior to doing this, the `if-statement` did not proceed. Now it does even when I remove the code that sets `standardUserDefaults` to YES is removed. Even if I remove the app and build and run on the device, the code proceeds.

This would indicate that the if check compares the YES to whether a `boolean` value exists there or not, and somehow the YES is persisting on app removal as well. However, the initial run of the app should have caught this too since a value existed. I checked this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040147/nsuserdefaults-bool-logic) and it seems that the if check should check for a YES value and not existence of a value.

This is for an IAP - when user purchases, the `boolean` is set to YES to show that it has been purchased, and if so, different viewControllers are presented to the user. How can I set this up properly so that setting to YES performs properly in if checks?

EDIT: Seems like this was in issue in Simulator on `iOS 8` - the default not deleting from the Application domain. Not sure if this is the case here on the device in iOS 9 or I'm just using `NSUserDefaults` incorrectly.

Comment: Haven't seen an issue on device before. Note that this information is better stored in the keychain than user defaults...

Comment: Could there be something about the domain? The first domain is volatile so it shouldn't persist, the app domain should delete itself on app delete.

Comment: No matter what it always returns TRUE now, cannot figure it out

Answer (score 0):

When you use the -boolForKey: method, it internally does 2 things. First, it looks up an object for the key and second, it tries to unwrap a BOOL from an NSNumber object (returning that BOOL).

If that NSNumber is not present, the return will be "NO". If that NSNumber is present, the boolean the object is wrapping will be returned.

To check for the reason NSUserDefaults returned NO, you may call -objectForKey: with the same key and simply test the existence of an object.

Comment: I'm setting it to NO with `setBool` method just as a test, but when I check the return value from `boolForKey` I still get YES. Doesn't seem to be any unwrapping going on.

Comment: Don't forget to call -synchronize every now and then. ;-)

Comment: Oh I'm synchronizing my butt of and still not workin

Comment: I am placing a -synchronize in my AppDelegate's -applicationWillResignActive and similar calls. When debugging apps, you often do not have a real use scenario. If you click on Xcode's stop button, no changes to the defaults will be saved.

Comment: I know synchronize best case is a few milliseconds, there's surely enough run loops to synchronize before any user interaction.

Comment: Synchronizing in this case means writing the contens of the NSUserDefaults to the persistent storage. But read my other answer, that's probably your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Apple states, that the method you use to import predefined settings won't save anything, it just adds the dictionary's entries to the in-memory defaults. I have not seen your whole code on my small display... [-registerDefaults:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/registerDefaults:)